# How to develop windows service to handle bat command

Tags: windows, perl, windows-services, command

We have webpage (in perl) on a remote host for submitting windows bat command request and the request will be sent to windows 2008, kinda like Jenkins.

The OS is: windows 2008, we have Visual studio 2008 and active perl installed.
I would like to create a windows service to handle the request submitted from webpage, and run it on Windows. So the windows service can be listening to TCP port, when the request comes, handle it.

As I am pretty new to the windows service development, could anyone shed some lights on it? The more detailed the better, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using Cygwin inetd as a service.
There is another solution which is using Jenkins Windows slave.